# Install pgadmin3 centos 6 with yum

Tags: postgresql, centos, pgadmin

I am trying to install pgadmin3 in centos 6. But I am getting this error. How to avoid this and install pgAdmin3.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install pgadmin3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=i386 error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrors.fedoraproject.org'"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=extras error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.repoforge.org/el6/mirrors-rpmforge error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.repoforge.org'"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=updates error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
 * base: centos.aol.in
 * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
 * extras: centos.aol.in
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: centos.aol.in
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'linuxdownload.adobe.com'"
Trying other mirror.
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'linuxdownload.adobe.com'"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.aol.in/6.5/os/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'centos.aol.in'"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.excellmedia.net/6.5/os/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'centos.excellmedia.net'"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.mirror.net.in/centos/6.5/os/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'centos.mirror.net.in'"
Trying other mirror.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Couldn't resolve host"` This is a problem with either your dns or your internet connection.

To test your internet connection you can test that you receive answers from the ping: `ping 8.8.8.8`

To test your dns you can test that with: `ping www.google.com`

If its an internet connection problem you can check that you have a valid gateway with: `ip route show`

If its a dns problem, check in your `/etc/resolv.conf` that there are valid entries like:
`nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with DNS entries disappearing being the problem...

try #curl http://www.google.com and see if the system throws up an empty resolv.conf file...

if so,

## vi /etc/resolv.conf

enter...
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

or use your isp's nameservers